# Почему в консоли выдает "Failed to resolve component: swiper-slide"

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

Хочу подключить swiperjs по официальной инструкции - [swiperjs.com](https://swiperjs.com/element#usage-with-vue)

Вот код моего IndexView.vue

```
<template>
    <swiper-container
        :slides-per-view="2"
        :space-between="20"
        :centered-slides="false"
        :breakpoints="{
            768: {
                slidesPerView: 3,
            },
            768: {
                slidesPerView: 4,
            },
            1200: {
                slidesPerView: 6,
                spaceBetween: 76,
            }
        }"
        :navigation="{
            nextEl: '.next',
            prevEl: '.prev',
        }"
    >

        <swiper-slide class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="logos-section" target="_blank">
                <img src="@/assets/img/content/logo-1.png" alt="" class="imgage-logo">
            </a>
        </swiper-slide>

        ....

    </swiper-container>
</template>

<script>
    import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
    register();

    export default {
    }
</script>
```

и он работает так как и нужно. но меня очень сильно смущают сообщения в консоли браузера:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: swiper-slide
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

> Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: swiper-container
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Первая ошибка чем-то похожа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601714/how-to-set-compileroptions-iscustomelement-for-vuejs-3-in-laravel-project

Comment: Вторая ошибка чем-то похожа: https://qna.habr.com/q/1221092?ysclid=lfjsk5wro5315521311

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи нужно создать функцию согласно [документации](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/api/application-config.html#compileroptions-iscustomelement):

```
isCustomElement = tag => tag.startsWith('swiper-')
```

Прописывается это в файле `vite.config.js` согласно [обсуждению на гитхабе](https://github.com/fetlife/vite-plugin-vue/blob/master/README.md):

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue({
    template: {
      compilerOptions: {
        isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.startsWith('swiper-')
      }
    }
  })], ...
})
```

Таким образом любой элемент начинающийся со `swiper-` будет считаться кастомным, два получаемых Вами сообщения указывают именно на эту настройку в `app.config`

Идея этой функции что она возвращает `boolean` значение в зависимости от результата выполнения, принимает `имя тега` как параметр (строку) и далее Вы можете написать любой сложный код который может обслуживать сразу несколько тегов? а не только один начинающихся на `swiper-`

Можно например так обработать сразу список кастомных тегов:

```
isCustomElement = tag => 
  ['swiper-slide', 'another-tag', 'my-custom'].includes(tag)
```

Так же, скорее всего, потребуется установить плагин:

```
npm install @vitejs/plugin-vue -S -D
```

Answer (score 0):

При использовании компонентов они должны быть явно импортированы в шаблон или установлены глобально в файле `main.js`

Для решения конкретной проблемы можно попробовать импортировать их в ваш шаблон в блоке `script`:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
}
```

В официальной документации так же есть пример с импортом в шаблоне: [ссылка на пример из документации](https://swiperjs.com/vue)